# jssor slider - $Align problems

Tags: jssor

I downloaded the JSSOR Slider FULLPACK and decided to use gallery "carousel-slider.source.html" from "demos-jquery" folder. ( http://www.jssor.com/demos/carousel-slider.html )

I set option
$Align=5
and option
$AutoPlay: false

no more changes in default code from pack downloaded at jssor.com

here is my options code

```
   var options = {
        $AutoPlay: false, 
        $AutoPlaySteps: 4,
        $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,
        $PauseOnHover: 1,

        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true, 
        $SlideDuration: 160,
        $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,
        $SlideWidth: 200, 
        //$SlideHeight: 150,  
        $SlideSpacing: 3,   
        $Cols: 4,    
        $Align: 5,   
        $UISearchMode: 1,  
        $PlayOrientation: 1, 
        $DragOrientation: 1,  

        $BulletNavigatorOptions: { 
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 2,     
            $AutoCenter: 0,   
            $Steps: 1,    
            $Lanes: 1,     
            $SpacingX: 0,  
            $SpacingY: 0,      
            $Orientation: 1      
        },

        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, 
            $ChanceToShow: 1,    
            $AutoCenter: 2,      
            $Steps: 4    
        }
    };
```

but it doesn't work, after refresh in browser slider starts at 1st slide.
can't find the reason why it doesn't work properly.

Number of slides in default pack (for carousel-slider.source.html) is 23, $Align set to 20 and $AutoPlay = false. Result is the same if i run script from apache url.

Answer (score 0):

The $Align: 5 works OK.
Please change value to 10, 20, 50 to observer the difference.